# CiviDiscount Code - Limit to Single Use

Tags: cividiscount

Can a CiviDiscount coupon be configured to limit it to a single use?

Comment: Thanks for your post.  It would be helpful if you could provide more information about what you are trying to do.  That way you are more likely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can put a "1" in the "Usage limit" field.  See screenshot below:
[image]